# How to change direction of this elements?

Tags: html, css

I use this [template](http://freehtml5.co/demos/crew/#fh5co-press) for my website skin. In this [section](http://freehtml5.co/demos/crew/#fh5co-press) of press have two div that contain text and image.I want change position of image and text. The image placed in left side and texts placed in right side. My site skin has rtl direction.

```
<div class="fh5co-press-item to-animate fadeInUp animated">
    <div class="fh5co-press-img" style="background-image: url(/DNN_test/Portals/_default/Skins/Crew/images/img_8.jpg)"></div>
    <div class="fh5co-press-text">
        <h3 class="h2 fh5co-press-title">Versatile <span class="fh5co-border"></span></h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis eius quos similique suscipit dolorem cumque vitae qui molestias illo accusantium...</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Learn more</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On `.fh5co-press-img` and `.fh5co-press-text` you can set the `order` property. Add the following CSS:

```
.fh5co-press-text {
    order:2;
    position: relative;
}
.fh5co-press-img {
    order:1;
    position: relative;
}
```

You are using `position:absolute;` for the elements, you have to add `position:relative;`.